# ERROR :The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage', but this

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

In my Asp.net core project, I get `ERROR :The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type MENTOR.Models.Mentor` error. What ı'm trying to do is;

In `login controller` I'm sending the login and password data as a parameter to API and all ı need to get mentorId(which property of Mentor) property from API response. Then all ı need to send this id to `Profile` action of `mentor controller`. Then ı will get this id from the session which comes from `login controller` then send it to API and fill the profile model with a response model. The difference of my question from other same questions is I'm not sending and model to `mentor controller` from `login controller`. All ı need is just trigger the `profile` action of `mentor controller`
Here is my `login controller`;

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(User user)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> userCollection = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> {
{ new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email",user.email) },
{ new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", user.password) }
            };          
            var result = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:3000/mentor/login", new FormUrlEncodedContent(userCollection));
            string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mentor>(resultContent);
            HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("mentorId", response.mentorId);
            if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Profile", "Mentor");
            }
```

Here is my `mentor controller`;

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Profile()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var id = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("mentorId");
            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:3000/mentor/getProfileInfo/" + id);
            string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mentor>(responseContent);
            result.mentorId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return View(response);
            }
            else
            {
                return StatusCode(404, result.mentorId);
            }
        }
    }
```

and my model of `profile view`;

```
@model MENTOR.Models.Mentor
```

thx in advance :))

Comment: you seem to be returning 'HttpResponseMessage' -  `return View(response);` rather result?

Comment: yess it worked. How could ı missed that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the error - instead of using response use result:

```
if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mentor>(responseContent);
            result.mentorId = Convert.ToInt32(id); //Maybe you don't need it???
           
                return View(result);
            }
            else
            {
                return StatusCode(404, id);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! How could ı missed that... :(